# Is docker commit an atomic operation?

Tags: docker

Is `docker commit` an atomic operation?

Meaning, does it create a consistent snapshot of the container's file-system at the moment of its execution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [docker commit running container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989845/docker-commit-running-container)

Comment: @helmbert, notice that question was not answered, so closing this one would only reduce the chance of any of them being answered.

Answer (score 2):

`docker commit` is not an atomic operation.

The only way to accomplish an atomic commit would be to take advantage of filesystem- or storage driver- specific features to support snapshotting, and to the best of my knowledge there is no such support in Docker right now.  Absent this support, there is always the chance that a file may be modified between the time the commit operation starts and the time it completes.